# What does ひとり残らず　たたき潰す それが俺の覚悟だ mean?

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble to understand this sentence. What does it mean

> ひとり残らず　たたき潰す それが俺の覚悟だ.

The translation I have come up with is

> Without one exception I will crush you all. That is how far I'm prepared to go.

Comment: I think it would be easier for people to answer you satisfactorily if you detailed a bit more what exactly you don't understand / struggle with / hesitate about, because the translation you came up with seems correct meaning-wise. Maybe there are some nuances you're unsure of for example ? Which we wouldn't know just from a tentative translation.

Answer (score 5):

Your translation of the first sentence is okay. 覚悟 means resolution, determination or *mental* preparation you make before facing some tough or risky situation. それが俺の覚悟だ (literally "That's my firm resolve") is basically saying he is determined to do it (crush'em all) no matter what, even though it may be followed by some bad consequence.